# Get 2 values from string using regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I got a string `"[5, 3]"` and I want to extract 5 and 3 from it using regex.

```
p "[5, 3]".match(/\d,\s\d/) # <MatchData "5, 3">
p "[5, 3]".match(/\d/) # <MatchData "5">
```

I can't extract both numbers at same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `scan` instead `match`, try:

```
p "[5, 3]".scan(/\d/)
```

What I can say is *`match` returns the first match as [`MatchData`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/MatchData.html), while `scan` returns everything what the regex matches*.

See [`String#scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-scan) and [`Regexp#match`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Regexp.html#method-i-match).